# MSBuild to apply a nuget package to a project at build time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I have a cmake project that builds fine on Linux and that I want to build also on Windows. The code is portable and is made of C++ so... it should build. The only thing is that, on Windows, I need to use nuget to restore some packages, cpprestsdk is one of them. Now when I run

```
cmake .
```

CMake will generate solution files and projects files that I don't want to include in my VCS at all. The thing I want MSBuild to do is to apply the packages contained in my packages.config to all the project files found in the project directory.
Anyone knows how?

Comment: Saw that with vcpkg I can install cpprestsdk. But... I want to see if there's an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing I want MSBuild to do is to apply the packages contained in my packages.config to all the project files found in the project directory. Anyone knows how?

I am afraid you can not do such things. That because whether you are using MSBuild or NuGet to do this thing, you have to use to the `nuget.exe` to do it. However, install nuget packages to the project file relies on **VS capabilities** not `nuget.exe` and nuget team not plan to bring it to the exe.

The NuGet Command Line does not actually install any packages. The install command is actually doing a restore operation.

This means that `nuget.exe` install will only download and extract the package into the output location. It will not modify the project file. Although, the package manager console seem to offer "`Install-Package`" for doing this, but you have to open each project files with Visual Studio and execute `Install-Package` in the package manager console for each project files, which is not what you want. So you could not enable this script outside of visual studio.

So we could not use MSBuild to apply the packages contained in the packages.config to all the project files found in the project directory.

You can refer to [this thread](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/509) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301482/add-nuget-reference-to-vs-project-package-from-command-line) for details.

Hope this helps.