# A package from a private Nuget Server (which has dependencies from nuget.org) does not install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget, private

Here are the steps that I follow to create and publish a class library to a private nuget server:

- Create a class library project using VS2017.
- Install **log4net** package from **nuget.org** using the nuget package manager.
- Open cmd.exe, locate the project folder, execute:

  **nuget pack**.
- Verify that the **mylibrary.version.nupkg** file is created in the project folder.
- On the terminal window, execute:

  **nuget push mylibrary.version.nupkg -source http://private.nuget.server**

No problem till here. Now let's consume the package from another project:

- Create another VS2017 project.
- Open cmd.exe, locate the project folder, execute:

  **nuget install mylibrary -source http://private.nuget.server -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**

At this poing I get the error below:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'log4net (≥ 2.0.8)'. 
Unable to resolve dependency 'log4net (≥ 2.0.8)'.
```

It seems that the installation of an external package reference relative to the private nuget server fails. Nuget.exe looks for the dependent package (log4net, for this example) at the private nuget server, not at nuget.org.

I tried many options (including creating and using a special nuget.config file) but can't find a way through. Any thoughts?

Comment: There was a known bug in nuget with the `-source` parameters: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4768 Make sure you are using the latest version. As a workaround, you can add your sources to configuration file and ignore `-source` parameters all together. If that still doesn't work, you can just copy log4net nuget package to your private repository.

Comment: What is result if you install the dependent package first with the command line `nuget install log4net -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`? If you can install it, then you can continue install your `mylibrary` package. If not, please share the error message here.

Comment: Again, Add Nuget reference to VS project package not supported with NuGet.exe. With NuGet.exe you can download the NuGet packages based on what is in the packages.config file. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301482/add-nuget-reference-to-vs-project-package-from-command-line. So, if you want add this package to the project, please use Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks @Peska. The issue is exactly the same. I already tried adding the sources to config but it did not work either. Eventually I ended up deploying all the dependent packages to my private server as you recommended.

Comment: @Peska, Since your comment resolve this issue, you can convert your comment to the answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.